# line projected to circle on a torus iff coefficient is rationnal

Tags: differential-geometry

I have to show thath the line $d\equiv y=\alpha x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is projected to a circle on a torus by the following $$p:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow T^2:(x,y)\mapsto (e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi iy})$$ if and only if $\alpha$ is rationnal.

Firstly, $\alpha=m/n$ rationnal$$p(\{(x,\alpha x)\ |\ x\in \mathbb{R}\}) = \{(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi i\alpha x})\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ Now, we show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism $$\varphi: S^1\rightarrow \{(e^{2\pi ix},e^{2\pi i\frac{m}{n} x})\ \vert\ x\in\mathbb{R}\}:e^{2\pi ix}\mapsto (e^{2\pi i(nx)},e^{2\pi i(mx)})$$ It is clearily surjective and injective and continuous and inverse is also continuous.

$\varphi$ is continuous:

Take $U'$ open in p(d).i.e. $U' = U \cap p(d)$ with $U$ open in $T^2$. i.e. $U = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n V_1^i\times V_2^i$ where $V_1^i$ and $V_2^i$ are open sets in the two circles. This means that $\varphi^{-1}(U') = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n}V_1^i$ which is open in $S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

The image of the line is not traced out as the parameter $x$ varies over $[0, 1)$. There seems to be an assumption that the points on the torus corresponding to the parameter values $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ coincide, but these points respectively are $p(0, 0)$, $p(1, \alpha)$ and so do not coincide unless $\alpha$ is an integer.

In any case, unless $\alpha$ is an integer, $\phi$ is not a homeomorphism. For noninteger $\alpha$, the image is a half-open line segment, which is certainly not homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: I'll make a correction